# jQuery UI autocomplete "no match" select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've read through nearly all the posts on jQuery UI autocomplete, but I still can't figure this out.

If there isn't a match, I need to append an item to the list that says something like:

**Create an entry for "*Search Term Being Entered*"**

so it can be selected and I can run a function to deal with a new entry.

The problem I'm having is figuring out which event I need to hook into to update the menu and list.

Answer (score 2):

This question may point you in the right direction:

[Detecting no results on jQuery UI autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718968/detecting-no-results-on-jquery-ui-autocomplete)

Be sure to look at the fiddle in Andrew's answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/VBTGJ/

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the server normally decide if the user entered a 'new item'?

I'm just making some basic assumptions here about your environment. The auto-complete list comes from some MySQL data. So the server should know if a term is new. Never trust user input from the client.

An autocomplete UI is not a way to force a certain input, it's merely a tool for the user to reuse existing or common values. The actual interpretation should happen on the server.

Comment: Yes - but if the search term isn't found in the list returned from the server (or local array), I still need a selectable item in the list instead of just closing the menu.