# Showing different panels depending on Autocompleter output

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a page that contains only a jQuery autocomplete textfield.
If the user performed a search and selected an item from the drop down list, a gird is shown under the autocompleter should appear *smoothly* containing the the data of the the selected item.
On the other hand if no data is found, a panel should appear *smoothly* under the autocompleter contains a couple of buttons and text.

Any tips on how to achieve this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hardest part of this is determining if no results were returned as part of autocomplete's result set, but there [are ways to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4718968/497356). You haven't mentioned if you're using a remote or local data source, or what your data looks like, but this should get you a good idea of what to do.

1. Pass a function reference to the `source` argument. Inside that function, do something special if no results are returned. Alternatively, you could write code like this in the custom event handler that's outlined in the answer above:

   ```
   source: function(request, response) {
       var result = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(src, request.term);
       if (!result.length) {
           $("#container")
               .hide()
               .html("<strong>" + request.term + "</strong> Not Found.")
               .fadeIn(3000);

       }
       response(result);
   },
   ```

   Here, I'm just fading in some content with a `<strong>` tag (I know you want buttons and some other stuff, but the idea is the same).
2. Define an event handler for the `select` event and show different HTML on select:

   ```
   select: function(event, ui) {
       $("#container")
           .hide()
           .html("<table><tr><td>" + ui.item.value + "</td><td><a href='" + ui.item.info + "'>" + ui.item.info + "</a></td></tr></table>")
           .fadeIn(3000);
   }
   ```

   This example just assumes you have a property called `info` on each item available in the autocomplete, and draws a simple table.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/wBePy/

---

**Notes:**

- Although it isn't intuitive, you can actually have any properties you'd like inside of each autocomplete response item. You can access these properties by name inside of event handlers using `ui.item.propertyName`.
- If you are appending huge amounts of content, I might recommend using some kind of client-side templating such as [jQuery.tmpl](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/)
- You can use `fadeIn`, `show`, or `animate` to smoothly append content.

Comment: Would you please check my code https://gist.github.com/1114466 ? None of my panels are shown or hidden.

Comment: @4bu3li: Just a quick glance it looks ok, but I don't know what the data coming back looks like...

Comment: A sample of data found: [{"value": "Owner 11"}] and a sample of no data found is []