# Jquery Autocomplete - no result message

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I would like the autocomplete to **display "no results" in it's drop down** list if no result are found.

My situation is like the JQuery default example.

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
        ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting no results on jQuery UI autocomplete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718968/detecting-no-results-on-jquery-ui-autocomplete)

Comment: Actually, this one is slightly different than the one I linked as a duplicate. Please disregard my close vote.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one way you could accomplish this:

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [ /* snip */];  
    var NoResultsLabel = "No Results";

    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, request.term);

            if (!results.length) {
                results = [NoResultsLabel];
            }

            response(results);
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item.label === NoResultsLabel) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item.label === NoResultsLabel) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Basically, you need to provide a function reference as the `source` to the autocomplete. Inside of that function, you can use the same utility function (`$.ui.autocomplete.filter`) to filter down the results. Then you can see if the results array is empty. If it is, you can add a default message to the results list.

The other two options I've specified prevent the **No Results** option from being selected or focused.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/er6LF/

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you Andrew. I can now go home.

Answer (score 0):

<del>This fiddle has a working is a functional example for you have: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewodri/wAg4g/</del>

<del>I changed this:</del>

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({source: availableTags});
```

<del>To this:</del>

```
$("#tags").autocomplete(availableTags);
```

<del>You can see it's running on the latest version of jQuery, and has the plugin linked on under "Manage Resources" taken from: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/.</del>

**Update:** The code above works if you happen to be using the plugin referenced... If not, it seems to work as is :) Please note that I did add the code within `$(document).ready();`, which may have been preventing if from working. Please see this forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewodri/VLKwe/

Hope that helps!

Comment: BTW, additional documentation on this plugin is available here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete

Comment: The OP is not using this plugin, he/she is using jQueryUI autocomplete (http://www.jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete)

Comment: Ahh, my bad! Check out this forked fiddle then: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewodri/VLKwe/. Post updated :)