# Jquery Autocomplete - empty source

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using JQuery Autocomplete feature.
The source come from url.
I wanted to know if I can know that the source is empty,
I mean i want to print alert message when the source the come back from the url is empty.

my code is

```
$(function() {
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: remoteurl
    select:  function (event, ui) {
        alert(ui.item.value);
        return true;
    }
});
});
```

Thanks,

John.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting no results on jQuery UI autocomplete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718968/detecting-no-results-on-jquery-ui-autocomplete)

Comment: I'm using URL and not callback function as in your link.

Comment: I updated my answer in the other answer to outline a solution for when you are using a remote data source. You'll have to convert the `source` argument into a function and make the AJAX call yourself.