# jQuery UI Autcomplete Check Number of Results

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

**JS Script:**

```
<script>
/* This function is used for multiple autocomplete input values */
 $(function () {

     var oldID = jQuery("#old_project_manager_id").val();
     if (oldID != null) {
         jQuery("#project_manager_id").val(oldID);
     }

     function split(val) {
         return val.split(/,\s*/);
     }

     function extractLast(term) {
         return split(term).pop();
     }
     $("#project_manager")
     // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
     .bind("keydown", function (event) {
         if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
             event.preventDefault();
         }
     })
         .autocomplete({
         source: function (request, response) {
             $.getJSON("<?php echo SITE_URL.'project/pmlist'?>", {
                 term: extractLast(request.term)
             }, response);
         },
         search: function () {
             // custom minLength
             var term = extractLast(this.value);
         },
         focus: function () {
             // prevent value inserted on focus
             return false;
         },
         select: function (event, ui) {
             var terms = split(this.value);
         }
     })
 }
</script>
```

And also this:

```
$(function () {

    var oldID = jQuery("#old_user_id").val();
    if (oldID != null) {
        jQuery("#user_id").val(oldID);
    }

    function split(val) {
        return val.split(/,\s*/);
    }

    function extractLast(term) {
        return split(term).pop();
    }
    $("#user")
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    .bind("keydown", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })
        .autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.getJSON("<?php echo SITE_URL.'somecontroller/someaction'?>", {
                term: extractLast(request.term)
            }, response);
        },
        search: function () {
            // custom minLength
            var term = extractLast(this.value);
        },
        focus: function () {
            // prevent value inserted on focus
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var terms = split(this.value);

            // remove the current input
            terms.pop();

            // add the selected item
            terms.push(ui.item.value);
            this.value = terms.join(", ");

            jQuery("#user_id").val(ui.item.emp_id);

            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

I have tried with `.length()` for searched term, but its not fetching correct result.

When user types something, this will display list of registered user. How can I show `No Result Found` message based on the number of records fetched. If there are no valid users, it will show the message else it will show the user list.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response

and then add/modify the response event in your code.

Comment: Check here `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718968/detecting-no-results-on-jquery-ui-autocomplete`

Comment: @Gowri, I am getting this error `TypeError: ui.content is null:if (ui.content.length == 0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add something like this:

```
$("#user")
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    .bind("keydown", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })
        .autocomplete({
        //Your code here
            response: function(event, ui) {
                if(ui.content.length == 0)
                {
                    //do what you want if no results returned
                }
            }
    });
```

Reading the documentation for jQuery UI helps: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response

Comment: It says `TypeError: ui.content is null:if (ui.content.length == 0)`. Also how can I bind `no result found` in search dropdown ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy Here is a fiddle working with your example running: http://jsfiddle.net/sphn33ww/

Try and debug in the response event. See what `ui.content` is for different responses and then make your function respond to that.

Comment: I tried with `if(ui.content.length === 0 || ui.content == null){` but it still shows me `TypeError: ui.content is null` error.

Comment: Well I changed the code to `response: function(event, ui){
                if(ui.content == null){
                  jQuery('#empty-message').html("No Results Found").show();
                }
                //else{
                    //console.log(ui.content);
                    //jQuery('#empty-message').html(ui.content.length + " Result(s) Found");
                //}
            }` and it worked.